# My Array program won't stop running

Tags: arrays

```
 public class Array
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    int[] x ={3,7,5,6,9,2};
    int maxposition=0;
    int max=0;
    int min=0;

    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
         if((x[i])>(x[maxposition]))
         {
         i=maxposition;
         }

     }
     System.out.println(maxposition);
 }
 }
```

It won't stop running and I'm new to programming, can anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: do you want use   i=maxposition value back in the for loop? it will never carry the value there.

Comment: This is probably an error like answered by jonhopkins, but a good practice is anyway to NEVER change the index variable when looping in a for loop. Some languages explicitly forbid this by the way. Don't forget to validate the answer so that the people helping you are rewarded for their time :-)

Comment: More importantly than imaginary internet points, accept the answer so future seekers with the same problem know it's the right solution.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
i=maxposition;
```

is resetting `i` to 0 every time `i` reaches 1, because `7 > 3`. I think you meant to do

```
maxposition=i;
```